# Why are field names from a Microsoft Form randomised letters and numbers when retrieving via the Microsoft Forms 'Get Response Details' connector?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I have a Microsoft Form with 4 fields of the following type:

- Text
- File Upload
- File Upload
- Choice

The connectors used are:

- [When a new response is submitted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/#when-a-new-response-is-submitted)
- [Get response details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/#get-response-details)

When I look at the `Raw Outputs` of this last step in Power Automate, the `body` returned by `Get response details` is:

```
"body": {
    "responder": "me@domain.com",
    "submitDate": "7/5/2021 3:17:56 AM",
    "lots-of-letters-and-numbers-1":  "text string here",
    "lots-of-letters-and-numbers-2":  [{.....}],
    "lots-of-letters-and-numbers-3":  [{.....}],
    "lots-of-letters-and-numbers-4":  "text string here"
}
```

This makes referencing the specific fields later in the flow difficult because they are represented by some sort of code or `id`, rather than the actual field names.

**Questions**

1. Why are field names from a Microsoft Form displayed as randomised letters and numbers when retrieving via the Microsoft Forms 'Get Response Details' connector?
2. How can I get the actual field names to be displayed?

**Edit**

Here is another example of the seemingly 'randomised' field names made up of letters and numbers, rather than the actual field name:

[image]

It's really confusing in this last example, as I only have 8 fields in the Microsoft Form, but 14 values available in Dynamic Content from [Get response details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/#get-response-details) that seemingly relate to form fields (6 of them are just random letters and numbers).

**Troubleshooting**

I thought "maybe the field names are id's because I copied the form?".

So I created the form from scratch and in the Power Automate flow run area, the field names are still just represented as 'id's' in the Raw Outputs.

The 'Dynamic Content' values available are both the 'id-like' names *and* the actual field names, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the output of the Actual Field names, you can use the **dynamic content**.

After the Get response details connector, in the next step, you can easily get the output with your actual form field names.

I created the flow with Title 1 and Title 2 fields.

[image]

I can get the fields with their name as below.

[image]

**Update: Get File Id**

- You can retrieve the properties from the File Upload object as below.
- Use the Parse JSON action and provide the sample JSON.

[image]

- Then you can iterate through the file(s) uploaded and easily get its properties from dynamic content.

[image]

**Note:** You can get the sample JSON from the flow run. Compose the File Upload dynamic content and you will be able to get the JSON.

Complete flow.

[image]

Comment: I need to access the field of type `File Upload` in order to get the `File Identifier` of the file that was uploaded so that I can pass the `File Identifier` to a `Move File` action and move the uploaded file to another location.  The value of the `File Upload` field is an `Array` with an `Object` within it with several properties, including the File ID.   So that is why I need to target the field more specifically and 'drill down' into its properties, and it would be easier to do this if the field name was available as a `key` and not just something like `lots-of-letters-and-numbers-2`.

Comment: @user1063287 check the updated answer